# pyspark read tab delimiter not behaving as expected

Tags: pyspark

I am using Spark 2.4 and I am trying to read a tab delimited file, however, while it does read the file it does not parse the delimiter correctly.

Test file, e.g.,

```
$ cat file.tsv
col1    col2
1       abc
2       def
```

The file is tab delimited correctly:

```
$ cat -A file.tsv
col1^Icol2$
1^Iabc$
2^Idef$
```

I have tried both `"delimiter="\t"` and `sep="\t"`  but neither are giving expected results.

```
df = spark.read.format("csv") \
    .option("header", "true") \
    .option("delimiter", "\t") \
    .option("inferSchema","true") \
    .load("file.tsv")
```

```
df = spark.read.load("file.tsv", \
    format="csv", 
    sep="\t",
    inferSchema="true",
    header="true")
```

The result of the read is a single column string.

```
df.show(10,False)
+---------+
|col1   col2|
+---------+
|1      abc    |
|2      def    |
+---------+
```

Am I doing something wrong or do I have to preprocess the file to convert tab to pipe before reading?

Comment: This works perfectly on my computer. I cannot reproduce this problem.

Comment: Okay, that is good to know, a bit odd though why it is an issue for me. I am using  ```Spark version 2.4.7``` and ```Python version 3.7.4```.

Comment: I found the issue, it was nothing to do with the code, and was the result of misconfiguration that hadn't been updated. Thanks.